# How to stub the sub method in ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec

Getting the following error when trying to stub the sub method:

undefined method `sub' for nil:NilClass

Why doesn't this work?

```
allow(String).to receive(:sub).with('xxyy').and_return('yy')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
allow(String).to receive(:sub).with('xxyy').and_return('yy')
```

Would imply there's a class method `String.sub` which accepts only one string as parameter :

```
describe "String.sub stub" do
  it "returns yy" do
    allow(String).to receive(:sub).with('xxyy').and_return('yy')
    expect(String.sub('xxyy')).to eq('yy')
  end
end
```

Are you sure the method you'd like to stub has this syntax:

```
String.sub('xxyy') # => 'yy'
```

?

This should be closer to what you want to achieve:

```
describe "'xxyy'.sub stub" do
  it "returns yy" do
    string = 'xxyy'
    allow(string).to receive(:sub).and_return('yy')
    expect(string.sub).to eq('yy')
  end
end
```